# Are Lewis Structures the same throughout solids, liquids, and gases?

Tags: lewis-structure

For example, is the lewis structure for water constant even when it is in a solid, liquid, or gas phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lewis structures are a representation of the atomic connectivities and electronic lone pairs present in an individual molecule of a substance. The molecule of the substance does not change in these states, so the Lewis structure would remain the same.

What *does* change in these states is the way individual molecules interact with each other. If you were to draw a diagram of how multiple Lewis dot structures of the molecule interact with each other, *that* would be different for these different states.